# File not processing under xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex

Why would such a simple file like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\U}{\emph{U}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathrm{C}}

\begin{document}
  This is a test.
\end{document}
```

process fine under pdflatex and fail under xelatex?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message shown by `xelatex`? It already tells you the answer (“Command \U already defined…”)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I am sorry but you missed the question entirely. It is not about what is wrong with the file,but why it works on pdflatex and not in xelatex.

Comment: Yes the error message shows the answer to that: Command `\U` is already defined in case of xelatex, but not already defined in case of pdflatex. If you already knew and had read the error message and were asking *why* `\U` was defined in case of xelatex, then you should have asked that in the question…

Answer (score 2):

When `xelatex` is used, `hyperref` loads the PU encoding definition files (it's for bookmarks), which defines `\U` as an alias for `\u` (the breve accent). I don't know the reason for this, as other accents such as `\r`, `\v` and `\d` don't have the uppercase counterpart defined.

If you're sure the breve accent is not finding its place in your document you can do

```
\providecommand{\U}{}
\renewcommand{\U}{\emph{U}}
```

which will work in both settings. But be prepared to get some weird result if actually the original `\U` turns out to be necessary.

On the other hand, I'm not sure what such a `\U` command is useful for.

Comment: I guess "PU encoding" is the short name for "Adobe PDF Unicode Enconding"? Would there be any other way that this can be accomplished within "hyperref" ? I ask because it is not just \U, but also a number of others like \C and \G, and these things are frequently used in source files for abbreviations.

Comment: @AlbertoG. That's the risk of using such abbreviations.